# Is class group of cyclotomic fields cyclic?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

What are the cyclotomics fields with a cyclic class group. I read that there are only 29 cyclotomic extensions of $\Bbb Q$ with class number one. But I wanted to know what condition on $n$ would make $\Bbb Q({\zeta_n})$ to have a cyclic class group.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: The complete list is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one#Cyclotomic_fields). What else do you want?

Comment: @abx  I am not just interested in the trivial class group. I am interested in the cyclic class group.

Comment: @Sunil: Sorry, I read the question too quickly.

Comment: What is the actual reason you are asking this: idle curiosity, or do you genuinely need to know for some further purpose? I doubt you're going to find a tidy rule that characterizes the cyclotomic fields that have a cyclic ideal class group. For what it's worth, PARI-GP says the class group of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{29})$, which is a cyclic Galois extension of $\mathbf Q$, is isomorphic to a direct product of three groups of order $2$.  This is the cyclotomic field of least degree over $\mathbf Q$ with a non-cyclic ideal class group.

Comment: @KConrad Thanks sir for the info.

Comment: Washington's Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields is a good reference for this sort of stuff. KConrad's n=29 example is discussed at the end of section 10.1. That section gives a way to prove that an ideal class group is not cyclic, although it's probably not general enough to fully answer your question.